# How to implement Response Caching with Minimal APIs in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, caching, response, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

In order to implement response caching, all that is needed to be done was:

- inject `.AddResponseCaching()` into the services,
- decorate a controller action with `[ResponseCache(Duration = 10)]`.

Now I'm trying the minimal APIs that come with .NET 6 and I haven't figured out a way to do that except add the header myself `cache-control: public,max-age=10`.

Is there a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: Can you share how you're doing this? I can't seem to understand how to do it with out the decorating tag

Comment: See the update for .NET 7

Answer (score 7):

`ResponseCacheAttribute` is part of MVC and as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-6.0) will be applied to:

> - Razor Pages: Attributes can't be applied to handler methods.
> - MVC controllers.
> - MVC action methods: Method-level attributes override the settings specified in class-level attributes.

So it seems that adding cache header yourself is the only option. If you want you can "prettify" it a little bit using custom middleware. Something along this lines:

```cs
class CacheResponseMetadata
{
// add configuration properties if needed
}

class AddCacheHeadersMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AddCacheHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<CacheResponseMetadata>() is { } mutateResponseMetadata)
        {
            if (httpContext.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't mutate response after headers have been sent to client.");
            }
            httpContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new[] { "public", "max-age=100" };
        }
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<AddCacheHeadersMiddleware>(); // optionally move to extension method 
app.MapGet("/cache", () => $"Hello World, {Guid.NewGuid()}!")
    .WithMetadata(new CacheResponseMetadata()); // optionally move to extension method
```

**.NET 7 update**

For .NET 7 you can configure [output caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#output-caching) (see the linked article for differences with response caching):

> The output caching middleware can be used in all types of ASP.NET Core apps: Minimal API, Web API with controllers, MVC, and Razor Pages.

Output caching can be done [per endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-one-endpoint-or-page) via `OutputCacheAttribute` or `CacheOutput` method call:

```cs
app.MapGet("/cached", Gravatar.WriteGravatar).CacheOutput();
app.MapGet("/attribute", [OutputCache] (context) => Gravatar.WriteGravatar(context));
```

Or for [multiple endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-multiple-endpoints-or-pages) via policy:

> The following code configures caching for all of the app's endpoints, with expiration time of 10 seconds.

```cs
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(options =>
{
    options.AddBasePolicy(builder => builder.Expire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
});
```

Comment: This saved my  - thanks so much @gurustron ! But i wish `Response Caching` was also baked in to .NET 7 (or later).