# MinimalAPI Action filter never get executed

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, action-filter, minimal-apis

I am working on a minimal API and I am trying to make an actionfilter for authentication works with it.

I tried to add my action filter directly on the endpoint registration likeso:

```
app.MapGet("/Users/{userId}", [ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomAuthorizationAttribute))] async (IMediator mediator, string userId) =>
    {
        //SomeCode
    });
```

I also tried with the attribute directly.

```
app.MapGet("/Users/{userId}", [CustomAuthorizationAttribute()] async (IMediator mediator, string userId) =>
    {
        //SomeCode
    });
```

At first I tried to make an extension to add it in a more elegant way and it didn't work either.

```
public static TBuilder AddCustomAuthorizationAttribute<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder) where TBuilder : IEndpointConventionBuilder
{
    if (builder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    }
    
    builder.Add(endpointBuilder =>
    {
        endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new CustomAuthorizationAttribute());
    });
    return builder;
}
```

There is my simple ActionFilter. I am placing my breakpoint under the onActionExecuting code to intercept when the attribute get called but it never get called.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context); //BreakPoint
   }

   public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context,ActionExecutionDelegate actionExecutionDelegate)
   {
        return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, actionExecutionDelegate); //BreakPoint
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Action filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0) are part of ASP.NET Core MVC pipeline and are not applicable (at least at the moment of writing) to Minimal APIs.

**UPD**

Starting .NET 7 Minimal API's will have similar feature allowing to use [`AddFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.routehandlerfilterextensions.addfilter?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method. See also [issue1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40506) [issue2](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37853), [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/40491), and [`IRouteHandlerFilter` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iroutehandlerfilter?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Is there any kind of replacement ? I would like to execute code before the endpoint gets hit.

Comment: @user3907939 you can create custom middleware and add metadata to your minimal api endpoint which this middleware will monitor, as is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754853/2501279) for caching.

Comment: Thanks that should work out for me

Comment: This will be available in .Net 7 (.AddFilter<T>)

Comment: @sharpc from what I can see it still will not work with filters from the MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Filters for minimal APIs in .NET 7 can be registered with the AddEndpointFilter method, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0